# Why is my code saying the answer is wrong when its right?

Tags: python

The code is supposed to be a simple maths quiz, however, when I enter the correct answer, it says it's wrong. My code is:

```
import random
name = input("What is your name? ")
question = 0
correct = 0

while question < 10:
    question = question + 1
    number1 = random.randint(1, 50)
    number2 = random.randint(1, 50)
    print("What is", number1, "+", number2)
    answer = number1 + number2
    print(answer)
    student = input()

    if student == answer:
        print("Correct! Well Done!")
        correct = correct + 1
    else:
        print("Wrong!")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `student = int(input())` Also, we can do without the "ASAP". SO is not at your beck and call.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to cast the user input to `int`, so replace `student = input()` with `student = int(input())`, as at the moment you are comparing `str` to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using Python 3, you need to type cast `input()` to `int()` in order to compare it with `answer` which is an integer:

```
student = int(input())
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming python3. The following is not valid for python2, as input treats an integer input as integer.

input() in python2 evaluates the expression with eval() function after reading from stdin, thus returning an integer.

The problem relies on the fact you are comparing strings to answer that is an integer.

```
import random
name = input("What is your name? ")
question = 0
correct = 0

while question < 10:
    question = question + 1
    number1 = random.randint(1, 50)
    number2 = random.randint(1, 50)
    print("What is", number1, "+", number2)
    answer = number1 + number2
    print(answer)
    student = input()

    #Cast the input to an integer for comparison
    if int(student) == answer:
        print("Correct! Well Done!")
        correct = correct + 1
    else:
        print("Wrong!")
```

Answer (score 0):

As many have already said, you need to cast the user input to int, replace `student = input()`

Also, you can do `question += 1`, rather than `question = question + 1`.  This can help speed you up.